# The ball doesn't move in Pong Clone

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I have a problem with my version of Pong.
When I type this code the ball doesn't move around the screen.
Where is the problem?
Please help me!

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball = SKSpriteNode()
    var enemy = SKSpriteNode()
    var main = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
        enemy = self.childNode(withName: "enemy") as! SKSpriteNode
        main = self.childNode(withName: "main") as! SKSpriteNode

        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 20, dy: 20))

        let border  = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

        border.friction = 0
        border.restitution = 1

        self.physicsBody = border

    }
}
```

Comment: Sebastiano how are you creating your project and where are you getting inspiration from?

Answer (score 2):

You are aware that this code line

```
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 20, dy: 20))
```

means

"If the property `physicsBody` of ball is not `nil`, call the method `applyImpulse()` on it"

aren't you? Okay. What will this code do if `physicsBody` **is** `nil`? Right, it will do exactly nothing. So have you checked that `physicsBody` isn't `nil` the moment this code is executed?

According to documentation of property `physicsBody`:

> The default value is nil, which indicates that the node does not participate in the physics simulation at all. If a physics body is provided, when the scene’s physics are simulated, the physics body updates the node’s position and rotates the node.

There is no code showing that you set a `physicsBody` on the ball object.

Comment: Have you used the SpriteKit Scene Editor?

Comment: @Confused I don't understand your question. How does that relate to my answer?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure the OP is making everything in the Scene Editor, and then attempting to "import" them and use them in his above code. Apple and some tutorial sites and services trumpet the claim that it's possible to get things done in SpriteKit without much knowledge of code. So this guy might be a victim of that, and may not have a clue about optionals and physics body creation, etc.

Comment: @Confused Well, using a graphical editor instead of code still means you'll need a reasonable setup. E.g. if I don't add an action selector to a button in Interface Builder, clicking this button also has no effect, has it? I don't need to write code but I need to reference between objects. So regardless if the OP uses the editor or not, the first thing I'd check is that note does have a `physicsBody` as if is hasn't, that would already explain everything. Of course, it may have one, then I will rewrite my answer.

Comment: Mecki is absolutely right by pointing out if the user understands how optionals work, and write an answer based on this guess.  Had the original poster used the optional in a correct way, then perhaps this question would not even have needed to be asked.

Comment: My point is this: You are posing a rhetorical question... "you are aware... etc..." when it's reasonably clear that he's NOT aware of such things, nor of (perhaps) even how to add a physics body, etc. So asking if someone is aware of something you (both) seem to be aware the OP is not aware of is... _fill in the blank_

Comment: @Confused `when it's reasonably clear that he's NOT aware of such things` This fact derives of from what? The OP said "When I type this code", so he has written that code himself and thus know enough swift to write such a code, so how do you know he has no idea about optionals? Maybe he just didn't know that this property is not set by default and was expecting every object to automatically have a physics body.